# how to read the json data from log file i will some log file please give me the best solution in java

Tags: java

I want read the log file. I need only json data.

```
Oct 30, 2015 1:48:30 PM SampleClient main
INFO: 2015-10-28T10:33:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"1.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-28T10:54:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00567","quantity":"1.0000","price":"550.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-29T05:55:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"2.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
```

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("logsstore/log.log");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while (true)
{
   String line = br.readLine();
   if (line == null){
       Thread.sleep(1*1000);} 
   else{   
       System.out.println(line);
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is the JSON always on a single line? Can you change the output format?

Comment: no actually i need only json in that log file .i want print only json data.i will give example

Comment: INFO: 2015-10-28T10:33:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"1.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-28T10:54:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00567","quantity":"1.0000","price":"550.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-29T05:55:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"2.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}

Comment: hey Manos Nikolaidis could you pls provide a simple code

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can just search for `{` in each line and get the substring starting from there. For example modify the `else` block in you code like this:

```
else {
    int cbIndex = line.indexOf('{');
    if (cbIndex != -1) {
        String json = line.substring(cbIndex);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

This assumes :

1. there is a single JSON doc in each line
2. there is nothing after the end of this JSON and before the end of the line
3. there are no other `{` before the JSON doc starts in each line.

Comment: but there is a exception came it is                                                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at SampleCure.main(SampleCure.java:47)

Comment: FileReader fr = new FileReader("logsstore/log.log");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    
       while (true) 
       {
         String line = br.readLine();
         if (line == null)
         {
           Thread.sleep(1*1000);
         } 
         else   {     
        
          String json = line.substring(line.indexOf('{'));
          System.out.println(json);

         System.out.println(line); } }

Comment: my log file               Oct 30, 2015 1:48:30 PM SampleClient main
INFO: 2015-10-28T10:33:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"1.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-28T10:54:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00567","quantity":"1.0000","price":"550.0000","amount":"0.0000"}
2015-10-29T05:55:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"sku":"F00211","quantity":"2.0000","price":"355.0000","amount":"0.0000"}

Comment: or i will give another example

Comment: ,,yes i tried ..i want to give my log file could you give the code